# ”My flow is super regular" what would it mean in the context? And another question related with it

Tags: sentence-meaning

Though I might be criticized like [**the previous question,**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/261324/what-is-funny-about-an-american-joke-about-the-british-actor-daniel-day-lewis), believing that this is an "English question", I have two questions.

Kindly watch [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FODlshClX64)(viewer restriction is imposed in some countries).

Since he speaks a bit faster "to me", an ELL, I watch with the subtitles and what he is saying is perfectly matches with it.

He says,(in Mexican(with English subtitle)) from 0.37～

> I didn't want to tell you because it's embarrassing.

His buddy

> It's not important. Love. It's Okay.

He

> It's the reason why we always sleep at your place. Okay **it's also because you have a Toto toilet.** **My flow is super regular**.

The first question is when he says "my flow", would he mean his excrement flows normally when he flushes?

The next question needs to go back. When he refers to Toto toilet, would he try to mean "because you(his friend) have a nice toilet?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Kentaro, I just want to add that I don't think anyone was *criticizing* you for posting your previous question at all. It turned out not to be a question about the English language, but that wasn't your fault, and I don't think anyone suggested that it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By saying "my flow is super regular," this character, Jaimé, means that he has bowel movements very regularly and frequently. He therefore uses the toilet often, which in turn makes him especially appreciative of his partner's Toto toilet. (The underlying premise is that Jaimé's own toilet is an ordinary American one that is much less pleasant to use.)

Jaimé has just admitted to his partner that he is a hoarder, and that this is why he has always insisted on sleeping at his partner's apartment, rather than inviting his partner to sleep at Jaimé's apartment. But then he adds that there is a secondary reason – he really likes his partner's fancy toilet, because he moves his bowels so often. This is supposed to be funny because 1) this second reason is so trivial compared to the first; 2) having such a strong preference for one toilet over another is a bit silly; and 3) alluding to bowel movements in such a moment would be very inappropriate.

Additionally, I guess "my flow is super regular" is supposed to be a funny way of saying "I have frequent, regular bowel movements." It's not a common way of saying this at all, but in this context the meaning would be clear to most native speakers. In American television comedies, unusual idiomatic  expressions are often used for humorous effect.

And finally, as @Michael Harvey has noted in a comment, this particular biological function is widely thought to be funny in and of itself, so that merely mentioning it can be an easy way to get a laugh. The English term for this kind of humor is **scatological humor,** and the term is often though by no means always used in a disparaging or disapproving way. That is, it is often used to dismiss jokes like this one as unsophisticated or vulgar. (For what it's worth, I have nothing against scatological humor but don't think this particular joke is funny at all.)

I'll also clarify a few other points even though they aren't what you're asking about: First, the main language spoken in Mexico isn't called "Mexican," it's called Spanish (or Mexican Spanish, if you need to distinguish it from other forms of Spanish). Second, this character is not Mexican, but Guatemalan, as is the actor who plays him. And finally, these two characters aren't buddies, but lovers.

Comment: "he uses the toilet a lot. This is supposed to be funny" I cannot avoid pointing you to the TV Tropes page headed [Toilet Humour
aka: Toilet Humor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ToiletHumour?from=Main.ToiletHumor)

Comment: _Its Always Sunny In Pennsylvania_ has an entire Toilet Episode in "Who Pooped the Bed?", crossed with a parody of a detective show, featuring evidence tampering and fecal forgery. Why this? As the eventual culprit says: "Because **poop is funny**."

Comment: @Michael Harvey, thanks for the links and yes, you're right – in the end, it basically does boil down to "poop is funny."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You are all busy on this. You said you never even click, but 4 sure you are the one who is most interested in.

Comment: @Kentaro - this your toilet question, not mine.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And who are you? The one who is sniffing around the toilet unsure longer than the "owner" haha.

Comment: But toilets are funny! Why can't we joke about them? Are you the web site policeman?